# No audio in Bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, bluetooth, wireless-headset

I have a Jabra Clipper Bluetooth headset which up until today has been working fine with my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T420s running Windows 7).

The problem is that the audio now seems to have stopped working. I can see that the audio is playing (e.g. if I look in the volume slider I can see that the levels are going up and down as expected), and the headset is paired and connected fine. The Bluetooth headset is set as the default one in the Sounds menu in control panel. I think the mic on the headset is working as the levels go up and down if I do a test on a VoIP application (e.g. Lync).

It must be some setting somewhere that I have disabled - but I have no idea what it is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 7 laptops and two Sony Bluetooth audio devices: MRD-NWBT10 and SBH50. I have managed to make both work automatically such that when the Bluetooth device is OFF the audio comes from the laptop speakers, and when the Bluetooth device in ON the sound comes from the Bluetooth device (so far).

Two things I had to play with:

1.

- Turn your computer Bluetooth adapter ON, make your computer discoverable,
  and then turn your Bluetooth device on and put it in discoverable mode
- Set up a paring
- Right-click on the Bluetooth icon and select ***Show all Bluetooth devices***
- Right-click on your Bluetooth device and select CONTROL
- When the dialogue box opens (and it might disappear quickly!) select CONNECT. For some reason this selection MUST be made by you.
  Windows 7 does not do it automatically
- Windows 7 will then establish an "actual connection" to the Bluetooth device.

2.

- Right click on the speaker icon on bottom right of desktop
- Select PLAYBACK DEVICES
- If the Bluetooth is DISCONNECTED you have to back and do #1. Make sure that #1 works! Remove your device and re-pair it if you have to.
- Make the Bluetooth device the default device. Afterwards I found that when the Bluetooth device is ON it becomes the default, and when it is
  turned OFF the default returns to the laptop speakers. Play with it.

I have no idea why I did not find this information anywhere else on the web. Number one (#1) 1 would have saved me a lot of poking and searching. But I am pleased now. And if the information does not work for you then at least you have more info as to what does NOT work.

AND if I had not been able to post here as a guest I would not have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try pairing the Bluetooth device with your phone and play some audio files. Then you will know if it is a Bluetooth problem or settings problem.

Comment: Yes I tried that so I knew the headset was working properly.  It now seems to have resolved itself - I updated the onboard speaker/mic drivers and for some reason that seems to have fixed the bluetooth issue as well.